# cannot delete rows from a remote access database

Tags: ms-access

I want to delete a table from a access database which is present on the web server. The query works fine on testing locally. But the same query gives an error . that could not delete some tables please help me....

Comment: I don't understand: do you want to delete the table itself, delete rows from the table or query the table?

Comment: Please post the SQL that fails along with the error message produced.

Answer (score 0):

Probably related to your rights on the remote disk where the access database is stored.

Answer (score 0):

Post your query and the primary keys, those may be the answer, but if it truly works locally but not from remote, then Shiraz is probably right.  The web server user needs to have write privileges on the file and folder where the database resides.

Is this IIS?